# MVC - Routing not working within intranet

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I don't know anyone can help but I'd appreciate any. I am developing an app in mvc (c#), now I had various routes working on my local development machine when the app was stand alone however now I've tried adding the project to the test intranet at work and none of the routes are working.

So where ***Localhost/Admin/Create*** worked fine locally where admin is the controller and Create is the action, when I try to get to ***testintranet.mywork.com/intranetsection/myproject/admin/create*** I'm getting a file not found error. I'm not sure what I need to change to get it to pick up the routing again rather than look for the literal path. The default.aspx page works fine and gets called but apart from that nothing. Is routing only viable when in a standalone project?

Cheers for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say what version of IIS you have deployed to, but you may be running into the issues described here:

http://blog.codeville.net/2008/07/04/options-for-deploying-aspnet-mvc-to-iis-6/

I believe that most people chose to resolve this using a wildcard mapping for the aspnet_isapi.dll.

Comment: I should have mentioned which IIS version, it completely slipped my mind. I am using IIS 6 and that post seems bang on the money to what the problem is. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're either running on IIS 6 or IIS 7 classic mode. If you can, I'd recommend updgrading to IIS 7 integrated mode. If not, I have a walkthrough for getting up and running on IIS 6.

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx

Comment: Cheers, it was that I was working on IIS 6, I'd love to upgrade but theres a chain of command with these things ;)